# XML - Oracle - Syntax to combine employee details into one xml output record

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Using Oracle SQL Developer, I need to get one xml output record for each employee that have multiple hourslost records.

If employee 1111 has 3 Used hours lost records, I want all the instances shown as:

```
<Employee>
<UniqueIdentifier>
    <NationalIdNumber>1111</NationalIdNumber>
</UniqueIdentifier>
<UsedHoursLost>
    <Date>2/01/2018</>
    <HoursLost>4</HoursLost>
    <Status>A</Status>
    <HourType>PTO'</HourType>
</UsedHoursLost>
<UsedHoursLost>
    <Date>7/01/2018</>
    <HoursLost>2</HoursLost>
    <Status>A</Status>
    <HourType>PTO'</HourType>
</UsedHoursLost>
<UsedHoursLost>
    <Date>8/01/2018</>
    <HoursLost>7</HoursLost>
    <Status>A</Status>
    <HourType>PTO'</HourType>
</UsedHoursLost>
```

Instead I am seeing a 3 separate xml result record:

```
<Employee>
<UniqueIdentifier>
    <NationalIdNumber>1111</NationalIdNumber>
</UniqueIdentifier>
<UsedHoursLost>
    <Date>2/01/2018</>
    <HoursLost>4</HoursLost>
    <Status>A</Status>
    <HourType>PTO'</HourType>
</UsedHoursLost>
</Employee> 

<Employee>
<UniqueIdentifier>
    <NationalIdNumber>1111</NationalIdNumber>
</UniqueIdentifier>
<UsedHoursLost>
    <Date>7/01/2018</>
    <HoursLost>2</HoursLost>
    <Status>A</Status>
    <HourType>PTO'</HourType>
</UsedHoursLost>
</Employee> 

<Employee>
<UniqueIdentifier>
    <NationalIdNumber>1111</NationalIdNumber>
</UniqueIdentifier>
<UsedHoursLost>
    <Date>8/01/2018</>
    <HoursLost>7</HoursLost>
    <Status>A</Status>
    <HourType>PTO'</HourType>
  </UsedHoursLost>
</Employee>
```

The query I am using that is giving the first xml example looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
XMLELEMENT("Employee",
XMLFOREST(
       A.EMPLOYEE "NationalIdNumber"
       ) AS UniqueIdentifier
XMLELEMENT("UsedHoursLost",
XMLFOREST(
         B.OCCURRENCE_DATE "Date",
         B.HOURS "HoursLost",
         B.STATUS "Status",
         'PTO' "HourType")) AS HoursLost
         )RESULTS
FROM TABLE1 A
 JOIN TABLE2 B
 on a.employee = b.employee
WHERE a.COMPANY_ID = 1234
```

How should the query look to get the second result output?

Comment: Correction Need to get the first result output not the second.  Also forgot to add the </Employee> at the end of the first result.

Comment: Can you provide samples of TABLE1 and TABLE2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `XMLAGG` can aggregate rows.  The function `XMLCONCAT` can put the elements together without creating one as a child of the other.

```
SELECT
    XMLELEMENT
    (
        "Employee",
        XMLCONCAT
        (
            XMLELEMENT
            (
                "UniqueIdentifier",
                XMLELEMENT("NationalIdNumber", a.employee)
            ),
            XMLAGG
            (
                XMLELEMENT
                (
                    "UsedHoursLost",
                    XMLFOREST
                    (
                        B.OCCURRENCE_DATE "Date",
                        B.HOURS "HoursLost",
                        B.STATUS "Status",
                        'PTO' "HourType"
                    ) results
                )
                ORDER BY B.OCCURRENCE_DATE
            )
        )
    )
FROM TABLE1 A
 JOIN TABLE2 B
 on a.employee = b.employee
WHERE a.COMPANY_ID = 1234
GROUP BY A.EMPLOYEE;
```

I used this test schema:

```
create table table1 as
select 1111 employee, 1234 company_id from dual;

create table table2 as
select 1111 employee, date '2018-02-01' occurrence_date, 4 hours, 'A' status from dual union all
select 1111 employee, date '2018-07-01' occurrence_date, 2 hours, 'A' status from dual union all
select 1111 employee, date '2018-08-01' occurrence_date, 7 hours, 'A' status from dual;
```